# Why the PHP function imap_search() is slow?

Tags: php, performance, search, imap, webmail

I'm creating a personal webmail but I encounter some troubles with **imap_search()**

I use this code but the function **imap_search()** doesn't stop:

```
$criteria = 'SINCE "'.date('d M Y', strtotime('- 1 days')).'"';
$uids = imap_search($mailbox, $criteria, SE_UID, 'UTF-8');
```

I've tried with a small mailbox and it worked slowly but it worked, however it did'nt with a big mailbox.
So I've tried to get only one of the emails with the same mailbox and a *'SUBJECT'* searching, it did'nt work either.
With this experience, I don't think the problem is my *$criteria*, and my **imap_open()** works successfully.

The biggest mailbox has a total of 9000 emails and 63 in the day. The smallest has a total of 20 emails and I succeeded to load all of them.

I've tried on different servers and it's the same behavior.

If someone has an idea, it will be very helpfull.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you instrumented the code or taken protocol traces so you can see if the delay is locally induced or is waiting for the remote server to reply the SEARCH command?

Comment: @Max By taking a medium mailbox with 42 emails, I succeeded to load them in 9.42s. The imap_search() took 9s of this time and with a bigger mailbox (9000) it didn't stop at all.

Comment: When I put _'ALL'_ criteria to the **imap_search()**, the array of 9000 **uids** is load in few ms and when I try with the _'SINCE'_ criteria, the function doesn't stop. Does it mean that _'SINCE'_ criteria for the **imap_search()** is not optimize for big mailboxes ? Should I filter the 9000 emails by myself in php or existing another solution ?

Comment: It sounds like the search command if your server is extremely slow. Can you directly connect and use IMAP commands to evaluate?

Comment: Eg, a UID search since on gmail takes very little time at all.

Comment: I have the exact same problem you had. Did you find it a solution???

Comment: I experience the same if I use POP3 boxes. I think POP3 has no search ability, so all message headers are downloaded, which takes some time.

Answer (score -1):

The example in the PHP documentation page for [imap_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) might be wrong. I just tried the following command against Gmail and it didn't work at all:

```
0003 UID SEARCH SINCE "8 August 2013"
```

...which makes sense because [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) defines dates in the format 08-Aug-2013, and in fact the following worked:

```
0004 UID SEARCH SINCE "8-Aug-2013"
```

So try formatting your date as such and see how it goes.

The first comment in the doc page also confirms the above.

Comment: I tried formatting the date like you say, but it's always pending. I also tried with the smallest mailbox, it works but as usual with the same problems.

Comment: Then try to manually interact with the IMAP server to troubleshoot it. If you're on Windows, you can use my client, IMAPTalk: http://gigi.nullneuron.net/comp/imaptalk.php

Answer (score -1):

try on your server and use this $mbox = imap_open('{localhost:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'your_user_name', 'your_password');